# How do i call one constructor into another, or call interface from each other in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, constructor, interface

i have a little completed design with c++. I have an interface that will be used for tcp communication. An inherited class from ITCP_message is TCP_Message sends data to IManipulate interface. IManipulate is inhereted Manipulator to manimulate the received messages and send acknowledge. Code  is shown here:

ITCP_message.h

```
 class ITCP_message{
    public:
        ITCP_message() ;
        virtual ~ITCP_message() =0;
        virtual void sendAck()  =0;
        virtual void getmessage() =0;
    };
```

I inherit this class to do actual work
TCP_message.h

```
#include "ITCP_message.h"
#include "IManipulate.h"
class TCP_message : public ITCP_message {
public:
    TCP_message() ;
    ~TCP_message();
    void sendAck();
    void getmessage();
protected:
    IManipulate* itsManipulate;
}
```

TCP_message.cpp

```
#include "Manipulator.h"
TCP_message::TCP_message(){
    itsManipulate = new Manipulator;
}
TCP_message::sendAck(){
....
}
TCP_message::getmessage(){
itsManipulate->manipulateData();
}
```

I have another interface to manipulate to received message. 
IManipulate.h

```
Class IManipulate{
public:
    IManipulate() ;
    Virtual ~IManipulate() ;
    Virtual void manipulateData() ;
}
```

I have a inherited class from IManipulate.

```
Manipulator.h
    class Manipulator : public IManipulate{
    public:
        Manipulator () ;
        ~Manipulator () ;
        void manipulateData() ;
    protected:
        ITCP_message* itsMyTCPMessage;

}
```

Manipulator.cpp

```
TCP_message.h
Manipulator :: Manipulator (){
itsMyTCPMessage = new TCP_message;
}

void Manipulator :: manipulateData(){
    ....
    itsMyTCPMessage->sendAck();
}
```

I want to manipulateData() function to do actual work and send acknowledge message with interfaces. But in main function i have a problem;

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    TCP_message tcp;
...
}
```

when i create object, it first goes TCP_Message constructor and there  *itsManipulate = new Manipulator*  . then it goes to Manipulator constuctor and  there itsMyTCPMessage = new TCP_message. then it comes back to TCP_Message and it crashes. How Do I call one interface into another or how do i allocte these pointer in memory?

Comment: Are you sure this is the the right code?  You're trying to allocate a type with pure virtual functions, so this code shouldn't compile.

Comment: Sorry in int main() i have a mistake and i edit now. The others true. It compiled. @StephenNewell

Comment: You have a circular dependency causing an infinite loop:
`TCP_Message()` -> `Manipulator()` -> `TCP_Message()` -> `Manipulator()` etc.
At some point your process runs out of stack memory from calling so many functions recursively. I suggest using a debugger to see how the execution flows.
Perhaps you can pass `Manipulator` constructor the pointer to the message it refers to, so you do `TCP_Message() : itsManipulator(new Manipulator(this)) {}`

Comment: Yes it is true. i understand why i am wrong but i couldnt find the solution. When i debug it, i see that you say. How do i solve this problem? @Jorge Bellon

Comment: This is a design problem, so you need to understand how you can turn the circular dependency into something that has no cycles (a hierarchy). I don't know the problem you want to solve so I can't help you with that (it is a different question too).

Comment: Actually i want to hold receive and send messages into one class that is TCP_message. I can divide it 2, one for send and another for receive. But i think this is worse idea. :( @Jorge Bellon